# Why is my fake speech detection model achieving perfect Train, Validation and Test accuracy but poor Precision, Recall and F1 score?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am working on a fake speech classification problem and have trained multiple architectures using a dataset of 3000 images. Despite trying several changes to my models, I am encountering a persistent issue where my Train, Test, and Validation Accuracy are consistently high, always above 97%, for every architecture that I have tried. However, the Precision, Recall, and F1 scores are consistently bad. I have also tried different hyperparameters such as adjusting the learning rate, batch size, and number of epochs, but the Precision, Recall, and F1 scores remain poor.

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting high accuracy but poor Precision, Recall, and F1 scores? And what can I do to improve them?

Model code:

```
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, precision_score

# Set seed values for reproducibility
seed_value = 42
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
np.random.seed(seed_value)
random.seed(seed_value)

# Define paths to dataset
data_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Finalspectogramdataaftersplit"
train_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, "Train")
test_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, "Test")
val_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, "Val")

# Define image size and batch size
img_size = (128, 128)
batch_size = 32 #32

# Create data generators with augmentation for training and validation sets
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(train_dir), target_size=img_size, batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='binary')

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(val_dir), target_size=img_size, batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='binary')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(os.path.join(test_dir), target_size=img_size, batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='binary')

# Define model architecture
input_shape = (128, 128, 3)

# Convolutional Image Encoding Block
input_layer = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

# Transformer Encoder
num_heads = 2
ff_dim = 64

x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=64)(x, x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)  
x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)

x = layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)  
x = layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Reshape((16, 16, 256))(x) # modified output shape

# Sequence Pooling Layer
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# MLP Head
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)#0.5
output_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Set up TensorBoard callback
logdir = os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/logs")
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(
    log_dir=logdir,
    update_freq='epoch',
    histogram_freq=1,
    profile_batch=0,
    write_graph=True,
    write_images=True
)

# Train model with TensorBoard callback
epochs = 40
history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_generator, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

# Evaluate model on test set
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_generator)
print(f'Test loss: {test_loss}, Test accuracy: {test_acc}')

#Make predictions on the test data
y_pred = model.predict(test_generator)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5).astype(int) # Convert probabilities to binary predictions

# Calculate F1 score and precision
f1 = f1_score(test_generator.labels, y_pred)
precision = precision_score(test_generator.labels, y_pred)

print(f'F1 score: {f1:.2f}')
print(f'Precision: {precision:.2f}')
# Save model
model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/originalmodel1.h5')
```

**First try:**

I trained same model above

**Result:**

```
10/10 [==============================] - 2s 220ms/step - loss: 0.2481 - accuracy: 0.9164
          Test loss: 0.24810609221458435, Test accuracy: 0.9163879752159119
10/10 [==============================] - 2s 211ms/step
Accuracy: 0.5017
Precision: 0.5017
Recall: 1.0000
F-1 Score: 0.6682
```

**Second try:**

I reduce some layers such as remove encoder block. because i think it cause overfitting.

**Result** Same like above

Code for evaluation

```
mport numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report, roc_auc_score, roc_curve, precision_recall_curve, precision_score, recall_score

# Load the saved model
model = keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/originalmodel1.h5')

# Set threshold value for converting probabilities to binary predictions
threshold = 4.4391604205884505e-06

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred_proba = model.predict(test_generator)
y_pred = (y_pred_proba > threshold).astype(int)

# Get the true labels from the generator
y_true = test_generator.classes

# Compute metrics
accuracy = (y_pred == y_true).mean()
precision = precision_score(y_true, y_pred)
recall = recall_score(y_true, y_pred)
f1_score = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
balanced_accuracy = (tp / (tp + fn) + tn / (tn + fp)) / 2
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_proba)
precision_recall_auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_proba, average='weighted', multi_class='ovo')
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_pred_proba)
precision_values, recall_values, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_pred_proba)

# Print the metrics
print(f'tp: {tp:.4f}')
print(f'tn: {tn:.4f}')
print(f'fp: {fp:.4f}')
print(f'fn: {fn:.4f}')
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')
print(f'Precision: {precision:.4f}')
print(f'Recall: {recall:.4f}')
print(f'F-1 Score: {f1_score:.4f}')
print(f'Balanced Accuracy: {balanced_accuracy:.4f}')
print(f'ROC AUC: {roc_auc:.4f}')
print(f'PR AUC: {precision_recall_auc:.4f}')
```

I have change threshold many times but no use. I think there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: Accuracy can be misleading if your dataset has a high class imbalance.  If you have 300 positive examples and 2700 negative examples, you can get 90% accuracy with: `lambda x: return 0` as a model because it will always guess the negative case, which is correct 90% of the time.

Comment: No i have 1500 +ve and 1500 -ve samples

Comment: why is your threshold so low???, shouldn't it be something like 0.5?